# Java equivalent to .net System.Drawing

Tags: java-2d, system.drawing

I have to port some C# code that makes heavy use of System.Drawing to Java.

Java has a limited 2D API compared to the API available in .NET System.Drawing. Is there a Java library that provides the same level of functionality as is available in .NET?

And if not, is there any guide anywhere on how best to accomplish in Java everything that can be accomplished with System.Drawing?

Note: I am not asking for a best or recommended library (which is not the purpose of StackOverflow). I am asking if a library or guide like this exists.